# Using .count in for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm new to oracle. I've come across table functions. The code for the function is

```
CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
id           NUMBER,
description  VARCHAR2(50));

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab AS
l_tab  t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows LOOP
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i);
END LOOP;

RETURN l_tab;
END;
```

Now, I want to create a procedure which will update the table type using for loop.
The code for the procedure is

```
create or replace procedure add_n_rows(n_rows in number) is
  l_tab t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
begin

for i in t_tf_tab.count .. t_tf_tab.count + n_rows
loop
  l_tab.extend;
  l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for '|| i);

end loop;
end;
```

I'm getting error saying that COUNT should be declared.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 37:
PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Could you help me out in using the right procedure for .count in for loop.Thanks

Comment: Get rid of parenthesis in the range specification of your second version of the `for` loop construct.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Please, post the full code of your procedure.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin updated the question with procedure

Comment: `l_tab.count` not `t_tf_tab.count`. `t_tf_tab` is the type. You reference attributes of that type through a variable of that type, not type directly.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov we are instantiating l_tab to be null in its declaration right. so l_tab.count will always be equal to zero.Please, correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: After instantiating(calling collection constructor) that nested table collection the way you do, you have an *empty* collection, not *null* collection. There is a difference. Yes, when collection is empty `count` method returns 0.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Can you suggest a method(procedure), such that I can update the table. not rewriting it entirely.Thanks

Comment: This appears to be a different question. So you need to [ask a new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) one.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov here's the [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676714/procedure-to-update-a-table-which-is-already-populated) question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the variable name not the type.

```
create or replace procedure add_n_rows(
  n_rows     in     number)

is
    l_tab       t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();     
begin

    for i in l_tab.count .. 1_tab.count + n_rows
    loop
      l_tab.extend;
      l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for '|| i);

    end loop;
end;
/
```