# Procedure to update a table which is already populated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure that adds new rows to an already existing table.But with the current procedure I've, I'm rewriting the entire table. The code for the current procedure is

```
CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
id           NUMBER,
description  VARCHAR2(50));

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;

create or replace procedure add_n_rows(
n_rows in number)
is
  l_tab t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();

begin
  for i in l_tab.count .. l_tab.count + n_rows
   loop
     l_tab.extend;
     l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for '|| i);

     end loop;
end;
```

Here, everytime I'm rewriting the entire `l_tab`. I want to update the one which is already updated. Suggest me the right method for the required procedure.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're re-creating the object. You need to pass an instantiated version of the object into the procedure as a parameter:

```
create or replace procedure add_n_rows(
    Pn_rows in number
  , P_tab in out t_tf_tab ) is

begin
  for i in P_tab.count .. P_tab.count + Pn_rows
   loop
     P_tab.extend;
     P_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for '|| i);    
   end loop;
end;
```

I've declared `P_tab` as an OUT parameter, this means you can alter it. If you don't want to do this then remove "out" and declare a local variable of the type `t_tf_tab`, which you can then alter.

You can then call it separately, for instance:

```
declare
   l_tab t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
begin
   l_tab.extend;
   l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(1. 'Hello');
   add_n_rows(3, l_tab);
end;
```

Comment: when I run the procedure, I'm getting the following error.
 `PLS-00363: expression 'P_TAB' cannot be used as an assignment target`

Comment: Ooops, yes that'll happen; I've fixed it.

Comment: When calling the procedure as indicated, getting the error `Subscript beyond count` @Ben

Comment: I've changed it @user3020454... I doubt you need to call the procedure after doing something to the object in exactly that manner though, you need to call it how you need to call it... it was nothing to do with the procedure itself.

Comment: thanks. it working. One last doubt. how you call the `l_tab` to check whether the procedure is executed or not.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't quite understand... the procedure will always be executed, unless there's an error.

Comment: may be my question is quite basic, as I'm new to oracle. I wanted to see the updated rows in 'l_tab'. so how should I call 'l_tab' so that it will display its rows